# Zend Framework include path

Tags: zend-framework, include-path

I'm trying to get the zend framework running, but the include path doesn't like me ;)
The zend directory is here http://mydomain.com/zend/

```
<?php
set_include_path('/var/www/www.mydomain.com/htdocs/zend/library/');

require_once 'Zend/Gdata/Youtube.php';
require_once 'Zend/Loader.php'; // the Zend dir must be in your include_path

Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_YouTube');
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin');

?>
```

And I get this error:

> Warning: require_once(Zend/Gdata/Youtube.php) [function.require-once]:
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /var/www/www.mydomain.com/htdocs/zend/index.php on line 4
>
> Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening
>   required 'Zend/Gdata/Youtube.php'
>   (include_path='/var/www/www.mydomain.com/htdocs/zend/library/') in
>   /var/www/www.mydomain.com/htdocs/zend/index.php on line 4

I have a smiliar setup on another server where it works, but here has to be something wrong..

Comment: Note: You should put the Zend package outside your document_root directory, like /opt/vendor/Zend or whatever. You don't want people to be able to request those files directly.

Comment: yes thanks. It's just for testing purposes right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want:

```
require_once 'Zend/Gdata/YouTube.php';
```

(note the capital T). Your other server where it works is probably using a case-insensitive file system.